# For loop does not finish

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I am making a game in Unity, 2D and for the creation of levels, I have added a for loop so that a number of blocks is generated a certain number of times. The problem is that it never ends, that is, instead of ending on the game screen when the two blocks are created, it continues to generate blocks infinitely.

```
public void GenerateInitialBlocks()     
{         
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        AddLevelBlock();
    }
}
```

I have reset the Script in Unity because it usually gives compilation errors or crashes, but it still doesn't work. Thanks for read.

Comment: Where/How is this method called?

Comment: What are the compilation errors?

Comment: The GenerateInitialBlocks method is called in the Start, so that when you hit Play in Unity, the LevelManager Script launches the number of default blocks that I indicate in the for loop. I have no compilation errors in VS or Unity.

Comment: well .. is this component attached to the objects you create via `AddLevelBlock` itself -> for each instance `Start` is called -> for each instance you create two more ....

Comment: The problem wasn't within the Start method call, because it removed the encounter line of code where it calls the GenerateInitialBlocks method and it also didn't remove the error. When in the For loop, you change the 2 to 1, the loop does work and ends, creating only 1 level, it does not create that level infinitely. for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe the problem could be in how many times the method is called.

1. find where in the code the method is called (perhaps using search)
2. make sure it's called only once per level and not repeatedly when refreshing or repainting (scene updating methods).

Comment: You believe so you cant know for sure, If you dont have an answer post this in the comments. Dont you answers as comments.

Comment: The method is only called once, at Start for the beginning of the game. I have it associated with an ArrayList of levels, when in the for loop I choose for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++), then in Unity, in the Array I select only 2 levels, which are the only ones that I want build. The problem is that it builds infinitely.